# Just upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04 in HP Elitebook but orientation option is missing in display setting and display is messed up

Tags: 19.04

Just upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04 in HP Elitebook

The orientation option is missing in display settings.
The display is upside down.

Do I need to install anything to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove below sensor:

```
sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy
```